# PHP Timezone error

Tags: php, datetime

I just moved to a new server and keep getting these messages:

> Warning: strftime(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected the timezone 'UTC' for now, but please set date.timezone to select your timezone. in html/manager/includes/document.parser.class.inc.php on line 1957

LINE 1957:

> $strTime = strftime($dateFormat . " %H:%M:%S", $timestamp);

and:

> Warning: strtotime(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected the timezone 'UTC' for now, but please set date.timezone to select your timezone. in html/manager/includes/rss.inc.php on line 50

Line 50:

> $pubdate = $modx->toDateFormat(strtotime($pubdate));

Do I need to add code to these PHP files? I've read I need to add this `date.timezone` to my PHP.INI file... is this true?

Comment: Um, the error message tells you *exactly* what you need to do.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about not having read the error messages properly.

Answer (score 4):

You need to update your `php.ini` file and set a timezone

Find:

```
date.timezone
```

And set it to something like:

```
date.timezone = UTC
```

Or like the error message suggest you can at the top of your script before any calls to functions like `date`, `strftime` or `strtotime` set this:

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
```

You should use the timezone that is best for your applications needs. I personally stick with UTC, but for a list of available timezones please see [PHP Timezones](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php)